# Query builder. Simultaneously Where() and With() methods

Tags: laravel-5.8

HTML form contains multiple  I send them to the server

```
$min  = $request->input('min');
$max  = $request->input('max');
$sort = $request->input('sort');
```

Sometimes the value of the inputs is empty and for this reason I use query builder:

```
$q = DB::table('adverts');

if ($request->has('max') && $request->input('max') != ""){
  $q->where('price', "<" , $max)->orderBy($col, $way);
}
```

but if I add ->with('images') I get an error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

```
 if ($request->has('max') && $request->input('max') != ""){
  $q->where('price', "<" , $max)->with('images')->orderBy($col, $way);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `with()` with `DB` class, [`with()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with) is applied to Eloquent Builder.

Example: `$books = App\Book::with(['author', 'publisher'])->get();`.

If you want to use `DB` builder, you have to use [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) to load related data.